# PlotlyRequestError: No message

Tags: python, plotly, figure, multiple-axes

I want to plot 2 graphs in the same Figure .. an error appears

> PlotlyRequestError: No message

i did this

```
`import plotly.plotly as py
 import plotly.graph_objs as go
 from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
 init_notebook_mode()
 trace1 = go.Scatter(x= X,y= Y2 )
 trace2 = go.Bar(x= X,y= Y)
 data = [trace1, trace2]
 fig = py.iplot(data, filename='bar-line')
 plotly.offline.iplot(fig)`
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First: you are wrong called `fig`. Usual `fig` specified as `go.Figure` or `dict`. Second: if you want to get two plots instead of one (you cannot get both in your `Figure`, because your `traces` have a different types - one for `Scatter`, one for `Bar`) you need to use `tools`. Third: if you import `iplot` from plotly.offline, just call it as `iplot` - here is not needed to call `plotly.offline.iplot`.
Here updated  code a little bit:

```
from plotly import tools
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
trace1 = go.Scatter(x=X, y=Y2)
trace2 = go.Bar(x=X, y=Y)
data = [trace1, trace2]
fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)
fig.append_trace(trace1, 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace2, 1, 2)
iplot(fig)
```

Also I suggested you take a look about [subplots](https://plot.ly/python/subplots/) - how to plot few plots at one page. And [stacked bar chart](https://plot.ly/python/bar-charts/#stacked-bar-chart) - maybe your goal is to get a plot as described here.
Hope it helps